# Using third party frameworks in Cocoa Touch Frameworks

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, ios-frameworks, cocoa-touch

I am creating a framework to abstract functionality around an API to be distributed to clients.

I have created a Cocoa Touch Framework and via following this [tutorial](http://code.hootsuite.com/an-introduction-to-creating-and-distributing-embedded-frameworks-in-ios/). I have ended up creating a aggregate target that builds the fat framework to be imported into other projects. I am trying to import third party frameworks into the target to be able to use.

Specifically, I am trying to use AlamoFire and SwiftJSON as part of my framework.

The problem is when I try to build the framework aggregate target, I get an error:

```
No such module 'AlamoFire'.
```

I have tried adding the framework to the Target dependencies of the aggregate target.[image]

There doesn't seem to be much information on creating frameworks, so I am at a dead end.

Comment: You will need to link and embed the Alamofire framework too. Have you done that?

Comment: I can build the project just fine, its when trying to build the aggregate target that creates the fat framework is when I get this error.

Comment: I think the problem is similar to-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31483110/building-a-swift-framework-with-xcode-7-beta-3-to-use-as-an-embedded-binary

Comment: I have run into the same situation I need AccountKit in my cocoa touch framework and getting error "Module 'AccountKit' not found" when adding my custom framework to another project. Did you find solution for your problem?